# Left join not joining as expected

Tags: sql-server, join

I have what I hope to be a relatively simple question.  I am performing a left join from a table to a view.  My source table only has three test rows in it. My SQL statement will join on of the rows, but not the other two.  I have validated the data to join exists in my view.  Below is a screenshot of my SQL statement with corresponding result set.  Additionally, I have queried my source table as well as my joined view to validate the data is there.

Any help greatly appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: Just a guess but maybe there are spaces at the end of salesordernumber?

Comment: I've gone ahead and inserted your screenshot, but you really need to include your query and schema in a code block.  Otherwise it's not searchable, and it's hard for people on small screens.

Comment: That would be my guess too. You can test that with `rtrim(expression)` to get rid of trailing spaces (and `ltrim(expression)` to get rid of leading spaces, though they would be easier to see in the first place).

Comment: Is your collation case INSensitive for the fields in tblOPTrack?

Comment: I figured it out.  The data in the source table was had been cut and pasted from excel.  Even though it was being trimmed, there was some hidden/non displayed character in data.  Thank you for your help.